# Is there a way to sort data from CoreData using a custom made sort descriptor?

Tags: ios, sorting, core-data, nsfetchrequest, nssortdescriptor

I am interested in sorting an NSFetchRequest in a very particular way. In my app, the user can enter a search query. I would like to return the results sorted with items starting with the query they typed in, followed by the rest of the items that simply contains the query.

For example: The user types in "de". I would like the results to be ordered in such a way where all of the results that start with "de" are first, followed by the rest of the columns that contain "de".

Here is what I would like the results to look like:

```
Deathless Behemoth
Deathmark
Deathmark Prelate
Deathmask Nezumi
Deathmist Raptor
Deathpact Angel
Acid Web Spider
Careful Consideration
Hell-Bent Raider
Jhovall Rider
Living Death
```

I've used NSSortDescriptors for other types of searches in my app, but there doesn't seem to be a way to use it for this specific purpose.

Here is the NSPredicate I am using to currently get the result that I want, but not in the specific order that I am looking for:

```
let namePredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(
    type: .or,
    subpredicates: [
        NSPredicate(format: "name BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", name),
        NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS[cd] %@", name)
    ]
)
```

Comment: Is the string stored in a single field? Generally speaking if you're using sqlite as the backend storage for CoreData (which I'm assuming you are) the sort is possible if it can be constructed by the sqlite's `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Majster It's definitely SQLite CoreData. I've done this type of sort before on another project (on Android), but in that scenario, I was able to construct my own query string. This was the magic that I used in my query: ORDER BY CASE WHEN name LIKE de% THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, name LIMIT 25 OFFSET 1